# How to make 'optparse' print menu by default if no argument provided?

Tags: ruby, command-line, optparse

I build command line utility and I use `optparse` for parsing options.

For now I can display my menu only by typing `prog_name -h`. How to show menu when no arguments provided? I want just `prog_name` [ENTER] and menu appears.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about: `if ARGV.length == 0; show_menu; exit; end`

Comment: really? is that simple?

Comment: I've tried. What I supposed to put in `show_menu` How do I reference `OptionParser` if I used it in the following way http://pastebin.com/wvFjie8U

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this before you define your OptionParser:

```
ARGV << '-h' if ARGV.empty?
```

Comment: This is nice hack, I like it. I found another way of doing this `puts option_parser.help if ARGV.empty?`. Put this after you've defined `OptionParser` object